# How to append a custom string before element of array using JS join()

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I append/concatenate some string before each array element using `join()`? For example the following code has an output like

```
One_Two_Three_Four
```

but what I want is adding the string `Step-` to the beginning of all items on join which can have an output like:

```
Step-One_Step-Two_Step-Three_Step-Four
```

```js
var steps = ["One", "Two", "Three", "Four"];
var stpstr = steps.join("_");

console.log(stpstr);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: `join` with `_Step-` and also add a `_Step-` in the beginning ?

Comment: Hi the `join` with `_step-` is adding the string  `_step-`  to the end of each element but as I asked I want to add to the beginning of each phrase

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
steps.map(e => "Step-" + e).join("_")
```

[image]